# jsonb function does not exist in greenplum

Tags: sql, jsonb, greenplum, hl7-fhir

When importing the fhirbase schema into a Greenplum database, an error is given that one of the necessary functions requires another one that does not exist within the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _fhirbase_to_resource(x _resource)
RETURNS jsonb AS $$
 select x.resource || jsonb_build_object(
  'resourceType', x.resource_type,
  'id', x.id,
  'meta', coalesce(x.resource->'meta', '{}'::jsonb) || jsonb_build_object(
    'lastUpdated', x.ts,
    'versionId', x.txid::text
  )
 );
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

It returned the error and a hint:

```
LINE 6: ...ta', coalesce(x.resource->'meta', '{}'::jsonb) || jsonb_buil...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Is it possible to override this function generically?

- Ubuntu-Server 18.04
- Greenplum Database: 6.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs for fhirbase](https://fhirbase.aidbox.app/getting-started) say "Any version above 9.6 should be fine" so it looks like your version of Postgresql is not supported. One reason for this is that the function `jsonb_build_object()` was introduced in [Postgresql9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.5.0/).

Is upgrading to Postgresql 9.6 or later an option?

The source for jsonb_build_object is in [jsonb.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c) so I guess it may be possible to back port it but as the last release for 9.4 will be [next month](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) upgrading may be a better option.

Comment: Upgrading postgres is not a viable option, but making this back port could be an option, but I have no idea how to do it. Was it just copying the files or would I have to make any changes?

Comment: The code I refered to is in C so backporting would require a bit more work than copying a file. Note that it looks like Greenplum is in the process of [merging with PostgreSQL 9.6](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/pull/8955) so the next release is likely to include the function.